# Stored Procedure parameters are different in SSMS Object Explorer to when the SP is modified

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms-2014

I have hit an issue that I am not quite sure what has caused it, or how to cure it.

When I view the parameters of a stored procedure in the object explorer of management studio, they show more parameters than when I right click on the same stored procedure and select modify.

So if I expand the parameters I get:

```
dbo.ReportSummary
      Parameters
          @Types (nvarchar(max), input, No Default)
          @month (int, Input, No Default)
          @year (int, Input, No Default)
          @groupID (int, Input, No Default)
          @subGroupID (int, Input, No Default)
          @dateRange (nvarchar(100), input, default)
          Returns integer
```

If i then right click on the stored procedure and select modify from the popup menu, I get:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[ReportSampleSummaryDetailsByAsset]
@Types nvarchar(max),
@month int, @year int,
@groupID int, @SubUnitID int,
@dateRange nvarchar(100) = ''
as
.....
```

The subGroup is now missing.

The intelisense shows the parameters the same in the object explorer.
If I check INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Parameters and sys.parameters, they both show the same as the object explorer.
The schemas are both dbo.

The compatability level for the database and management studio are both Microsoft Sql Server 2014.

If it helps any, this is a backup of the publisher database.

What I need to know is:

Why are they different?

and

how do I make the parameters the same in the SP that I modify?

Answer (score 2):

Refresh your object explorer.  It needs to be explicitly refreshed when changes have been made to the underlying objects.

Right click on the procedure, and click "Refresh", then re-expand it.

Comment: Hi @Tab, thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately it didn't work.  I've refreshed from the parameters up, by right clicking and selecting refresh.  If it makes any difference I haven't made any changes to the SP since the DB was restored.

Comment: Then I don't think I've ever seen what you are describing.   Can you list all the steps needed to reproduce the issue?   What happens if you execute the ALTER PROC script, and then close and re-open SSMS?

Comment: Hi @Tab.  To reproduce the behaviour:  Backup the publisher database (overwrtite existing backup sets, backup type full).  Copy it to my dev environment.  Restore the database over an existing one (Overwrite existing database checked, not preserving replication settings).  Right click and refersh from the parameters up. If I then expand the SP the parameters that is shows are different two the ones you get from the modify SP.  I've just tried the ALTER PROC, just to make sure, and unfortunately it hasn't fixed it.

Comment: What happens if you make some small change to the proc and ALTER it?   It doesn't have to change the functionality.   Add a comment or whitespace or something meaningless.  Is there any difference in Version or Edition in the SQL Servers that you backed up and restored on?

Comment: Hi @Tab.  Making a change to the SP, hasn't changed the parameters in management studio unfortunately.  I've checked the SQL servers, both are running 2014 Standard 64-bit, and both have the compatability level of the DB set to 2014.

Comment: I recommend that you cross-post this question on dba.stackexchange.com.   I've never had this happen and be a persistent problem.  It makes me think that you have corruption in either your database, or your SSMS software.